# Simple integration question with upper and lower limits

Tags: calculus, integration

How to calculate $\int_{a}^{2a} (\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{x}) dx$?

I tried putting it in Mathway or Symbolab and the answer they gave me was $\frac 13(5-4{\sqrt 2})a^\frac{3}{2}$. I calculated it myself and got $\frac{a^{3\over2}}{3}$. What have I done wrong?

Comment: I've answered it but I can't post here since it's been put on hold

Comment: ∫√a dx - ∫√x dx from a to 2a. Will evaluate to [x√a] - [2/3(x^(3/2))] from a to 2a. And work from there.